Is there a copy-only zap-to-char?
I'm using zap-to-char more and more. But sometimes, I want to copy rather than kill. Is there a function for this in an out-of-the-box copy of Emacs? I could surely write the code myself, but does such a function already exist by default? The documentation is very sparse on copying.

You can always undo (C-x u) or yank (C-y) after the zap. The zapped text is at the front of the kill ring.

@NickD I came to the same conclusion, but it's rather sad!

Go Evil -- Vim emulation in Emacs. The action to copy to character "a" would then be "yta" in Normal mode/state, "y" yank/copy, "t" to, "a".

The built-in approach would probably be to use isearch. For example:
C-s z M-w would search (and mark) forward to the character z and then copy the text.
You might also be interested in a package like Avy that lets you use visible characters as a target for various actions including jumping, deleting, copying, etc. Avy is fairly simple to set up and use, but it can also be very powerful (as described in this blog post).
